# How can I display average at the end of the results

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a query that gives average of prices for every month for each of the three different brands, I want to display in the last row also average of the three brands combined.

Below is the subquery for january month, I have a similar subquery for each of the other months and the main query displays all the month with average for each brand. I want to add a row at the end with the average of the total of the three brand

```sql
with a1 as (
  (
    SELECT 
      brand, 
      round(AVG(Price), 2) avg_jan,
      0 as avg_feb, 0 as avg_march, 0 as avg_april, 0 as avg_may,
      0 as avg_june, 0 as avg_july, 0 as avg_aug
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        item, 
        SUM(price) Price, 
        count(DISTINCT(item) cnt, 
        brand
      FROM myTable 
      GROUP BY item, brand
    )
    GROUP BY brand
  )
),

...
select a1.brand, a1.avg_jan,...
from a1 
left join a2 on a1.brand = a2.brand
```

## this is how should look

### brand | avg_jan | avg_feb | ...

### X       ...        ...

### Y       ...        ...

### total   ...        ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT item, SUM(price) Price, 
  count(DISTINCT(item) cnt,
  brand
 FROM myTable group by item, brand)
group by ROLLUP(brand);
```

Comment: yeah, that is what I have been trying but in the main query doesnt matter what join I try it only gives one 'total average from the rollups

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky, but what about adding a `UNION` at the end:

```sql
with a1 as (
  ...
),
...
-- Get detailed rows (original query)
select a1.brand, a1.avg_jan,...
from a1 
left join a2 on a1.brand = a2.brand

union all

-- Get one additional summary row
select 'total', avg(a1.avg_jan), avg(a2.avg_feb)...
from a1 
left join a2 on a1.brand = a2.brand
```

**Update**
Assuming you have a `purchase_date` field in your table, this will also give you the monthly price averages per brand:

```sql
SELECT 
  brand,
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 1 THEN price END) AS avg_jan,
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 2 THEN price END) AS avg_feb,
  ...
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 12 THEN price END) AS avg_dec
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY brand

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'Total',
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 1 THEN price END),
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 2 THEN price END),
  ...
  AVERAGE(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) = 12 THEN price END)
FROM MyTable
```

Looking at your original query, how are you using `item` and `cnt`?

For the `total` row, I assume you want an overall average and not the "average of averages".  For example, brand X sells 1000 items at an average price of $10 and brand Y sells 100 items at an average price of $20, the total average would be: `( ($10 * 1000) + ($20 * 100) ) / (1000 + 100) = $10.91`.

Comment: that works for sure but I want to avoid writing so many lines, I was wondering if there is some way to simplify all that repetitive code

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.  See the new query I put in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the assumption from above that you have a purchase date column, I think the following query will suit your needs:

```sql
WITH avg_sales AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT brand, to_char(purchase_date, 'MM') AS MONTH, price
        FROM myTable)
  PIVOT (AVG(price) AS AVG FOR MONTH IN ('01' AS JAN, '02' AS FEB, '03' AS MAR, '04' AS APR,
                                         '05' AS MAY, '06' AS JUN, '07' AS JUL, '08' AS AUG,
                                         '09' AS SEP, '10' AS OCT, '11' AS NOV, '12' AS DEC))
)
SELECT *
FROM avg_sales
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', 
       avg(jan_avg), avg(feb_avg), avg(mar_avg), avg(apr_avg),
       avg(may_avg), avg(jun_avg), avg(jul_avg), avg(aug_avg),
       avg(sep_avg), avg(oct_avg), avg(nov_avg), avg(dec_avg)
FROM avg_sales;
```

This would aggregate across multiple years as it is written now, but you can limit your results with a BETWEEN in the WHERE clause of the innermost query or something similar.

Additionally, if you were set on using ROLLUP, the following query would work:

```sql
SELECT DECODE(GROUPING(brand), 1, 'Total', brand) AS BRAND, 
       AVG(JAN_AVG) AS JAN_AVG, AVG(FEB_AVG) AS FEB_AVG, AVG(MAR_AVG) AS MAR_AVG, AVG(APR_AVG) AS APR_AVG,
       AVG(MAY_AVG) AS MAY_AVG, AVG(JUN_AVG) AS JUN_AVG, AVG(JUL_AVG) AS JUL_AVG, AVG(AUG_AVG) AS AUG_AVG,
       AVG(SEP_AVG) AS SEP_AVG, AVG(OCT_AVG) AS OCT_AVG, AVG(NOV_AVG) AS NOV_AVG, AVG(DEC_AVG) AS DEC_AVG
FROM (SELECT brand, to_char(purchase_date, 'MM') AS MONTH, price
      FROM myTable)
PIVOT (AVG(price) AS AVG FOR MONTH IN ('01' AS JAN, '02' AS FEB, '03' AS MAR, '04' AS APR,
                                       '05' AS MAY, '06' AS JUN, '07' AS JUL, '08' AS AUG,
                                       '09' AS SEP, '10' AS OCT, '11' AS NOV, '12' AS DEC))
GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand)
ORDER BY GROUPING(brand), brand;
```